UFT getting error as "{Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified"
I have successfully configured ODBC 64 bit and pop up appears "connection successful" and tried to automate using UFT, but I get the error:

Data source name not found and no default driver specified.

Dim objConnection
Dim objRecordSet
Dim connectionString
' Create ADODB connection object
Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

' Create Recordset object
Set objRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

connectionString  = "DRIVER={Oracle in OraClient19Home1};UID=" & UID_inp & ";PWD=" & PWD_inp & ";DBQ=" & Database & ".WORLD"

On Error Resume Next ' Enable error handling

' Try to open the connection
objConnection.Open connectionString

If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    ' Connection failed, display error message
    MsgBox "Connection failed: " & Err.Description, vbCritical, "Connection Error"
Else
    ' Connection succeeded, display success message
    MsgBox "Connection successful!", vbInformation, "Connection Status"
    ' Close the connection
    objConnection.Close
End If


It would help to see some code, how you are calling the ODBC driver, what the connection string is etc. My initial guess would be your app is in a 32-bit context so it doesn't find the 64-bit driver, that's a common issue.

Please do not post code in comments, instead [edit] the question and add the code using the editor.

How are you triggering the script through UFT?

yes..i am triggering the execution with uft

We know that, I asked how?

using connectionstring to connect db to execute query through UFT

I mean how is the VBScript being executed through UFT, do you have to set up a command to call the VBScript, if so what is that command? Usually, I'd expect something like %COMSPEC% /k %systemroot%\SysWOW64\cscript.exe "path\to\my\file.vbs"?
